# Permission- / Roleframework in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, permissions, user-roles

I've a 3-tier application (client, server, dbms) and I'm looking for an Permission- /roleframework. I know a Role- / Permissionframework in Java EE with GlassFish. The framework that I'm looking for, should approach.

With the permissions I want to verify that a user in a specific role can use a business case.

Do you know something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .NET you would typically use the built in Membership provider. You can use it out of the box, or implement a set of interfaces that will give you all the functionality you need.
You can find all the info about it here :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479021.aspx

This question on SO has more details on why you might want to use it:

[Is *not* using the asp.net membership provider a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969043/is-not-using-the-asp-net-membership-provider-a-bad-idea)

[Rhino.Security](https://github.com/ayende/rhino-security) would be an existing alternative. I have never used it myself though, so I cannot recommend it.
You will find a lot of info on this blog : http://ayende.com/blog/tags/rhino-security

Comment: Rhino.Security has not been updated in nearly a decade.